# How to assign USB devices and monitors to a virtual machine like a thin client?

Tags: thin-client, multiple-computers

Using Windows 8.1 pro I am trying to set up my PC as a server that can run as different PCs (whether virtual or with thin clients) in different rooms in my house. I don't know how to configure this in Windows if it is possible or if there is any specialty software for this. If I have to I will end up buying a thin client, but the type I need to run dual monitors is a little more pricey than I'd like to spend.

Basically my setup is like this: PC hooked up to television with gaming controllers as a steam machine. I have dual monitors in an office upstairs with keyboard, mouse, speakers and printer. I was using long HDMI and USB cables to plug in. I want to be able to use this as a separate PC. In the future I would even like to add additional monitors in other rooms to act as other standalone machines. I have just been extending the desktop for now, but if there is a time where both are being used at the same time this won't work.

Comment: I've been researching this for a while and I found some software called BeTwin by ThinSoft. This is probably my best solution, but I'll give some more time for someone to answer if they have a better homemade solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several applications that could solve this problem. Windows Multipoint Server will do exactly this. Other software include BeTwin by ThinSoft that allows you to decide which attached monitors and USB devices operate under a specific user using one PC.